# Fan Setting For Portable Air Conditioner

Tags: air-conditioning, fans

Optimal fan speed for a window air conditioner has been addressed before.  However, the thermodynamics are different for portables.  A single hose portable (dual hoses too big for small rooms) sucks hot air from outside the room, separates the mixed air into hot air and cool air by heat exchange.  Hot air is vented outside, and cool air is directed into the room.  A low fan speed sucks less hot air into the room, but it isn't exchanging the cold from the compressor as efficiently.

It seems that the high/low fan speed choice is determined by the temperature differential between the room and the outside air entering the room.  If it's blazing hot outside with a high fan setting, then the extra hot air drawn into the room cannot be cooled down enough to take advantage of the more efficient heat exchange.  So, any ideas on how to figure out when to reduce the fan setting for optimal perceived cool temperature?  Perhaps it's a function of humidity, too.

Comment: You have a problem with your model of a single house AC unit. Hot air is not sucked in to the unit and split. There are two independent blowers: one for the evaporator, and a second for the condenser. The condenser blower is the one that draws in the room air, passes it over the condenser, and exhausts it out the tube. The other blower only circulates air already in the room through the evaporator. This blower is variable speed. However, the condenser blower runs at a fixed speed, so the amount of air drawn in to the room does not vary.

Comment: ideally you could throttle between hi and low with a proportional control. You could then slowly wind down until the temp stabilizes or goes up, then tick up the speed a notch to the min needed to maintain the set point.